# UIBarButtonItems not calling actions

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I've created a UIToolBar with UIBarButtonItems but when I tap them, the selector's are not being called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Based on suggestions in the comments, I modified my code, but unfortunately, the buttons still do not work.

```
-(void)buildBottomMenu
{
    UIImage *newsImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"243-globe"];
    UIBarButtonItem *newsBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:newsImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadHome)];

    UIImage *weatherImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"25-weather"];
    UIBarButtonItem *weatherBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:weatherImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadWeather)];

    UIImage *sportsImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"63-runner"];
    UIBarButtonItem *sportsBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:sportsImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadSports)];

    UIImage *entrnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"178-city"];
    UIBarButtonItem *entrnBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:entrnImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadEntertainment)];

    UIImage *videoImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"69-display"];
    UIBarButtonItem *videoBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:videoImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadVideoPage)];

    UIImage *moreImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"259-list"];
    UIBarButtonItem *moreBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:moreImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadOptionsPage)];

    UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                              target:nil action:nil];

    [_bottomBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,newsBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                      weatherBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                      sportsBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                      entrnBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                      videoBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                      moreBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                      nil]];

    [self.view addSubview:_bottomBar];
}
```

Here is a sample selector:

```
- (void)loadWeather
{
    NSLog(@"Loading weather");
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating `UIButton` objects to put in the toolbar? Try creating the `UIBarButtonItem` with the `initWithImage...` method.

Comment: also make sure the selectors you have chosen do not take any parameters. If you'd like to pass the sender to the selector with the parameter `loadOptionsPage:(id)sender` make sure to include a trailing colon to the names of your selector. e.g. `@selector(loadOptionsPage:)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rmaddy, I made the change, but still no luck with the buttons working. atreat, the selectors don't take parameters.

Comment: It might not solve your problem but you should add extension i.e .png in imangeNamed method argument

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, but I just realized that it was something I was doing in my viewDidLayoutSubviews method that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

-->First drog and drop UIToolbar to your ViewController.xib

-->connect IBOutlet connection

**ViewController.h**

```
IBOutlet UIToolbar *_bottomBar;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self buildBottomMenu];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


-(void)buildBottomMenu
{
UIImage *newsImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"243-globe"];
UIBarButtonItem *newsBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:newsImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadHome)];

UIImage *weatherImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"25-weather"];
UIBarButtonItem *weatherBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:weatherImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadWeather)];

UIImage *sportsImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"63-runner"];
UIBarButtonItem *sportsBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:sportsImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadSports)];

UIImage *entrnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"178-city"];
UIBarButtonItem *entrnBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:entrnImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadEntertainment)];

UIImage *videoImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"69-display"];
UIBarButtonItem *videoBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:videoImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadVideoPage)];

UIImage *moreImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"259-list"];
UIBarButtonItem *moreBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:moreImg style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadOptionsPage)];

UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:nil action:nil];

[_bottomBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace,newsBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                  weatherBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                  sportsBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                  entrnBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                  videoBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                  moreBtnItem,flexibleSpace,
                  nil]];

[self.view addSubview:_bottomBar];
 }



 - (void)loadWeather
 {
  NSLog(@"Loading weather");
 }
```